# WCF Service Memory Leaks

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, memory-leaks

I have a very small wcf service hosted in a console app.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoService();
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public void DoService()
    {

    }
}
```

and its being called as

```
using (ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client())
{
    client.DoService(new DoServiceRequest());
    client.Close();
}
```

Please remember that service is published on basicHttpBindings.

**Problem**

Now when i performed above client code in a loop of 1000 i found big difference between "All Heap bytes" and "Private Bytes" performance counters (i used .net memory profiler). After investigation i found some of the objects are not properly disposed 
following are the list of those objects (1000 undisposed instance were found --> equals to the client calls)

(namespace for all of them is System.ServiceModel.Channels)

```
HttpOutput.ListenerResponseHttpOutput.ListenerResponseOutputStream
BodyWriterMessage
BufferedMessage
HttpRequestContext.ListenerHttpContext.ListenerContextHttpInput.ListenerContextInputStream
HttpRequestContext.ListenerHttpContext
```

**Questions**
Why do we have lot of undisposed objects and how to control them.

Please Help

Comment: Looks like a system library leak to me. Client(as in user written service) code doesn't touch those buffers and streams, and looks like WCF is not disposing them.

Comment: Mabushar: Have you had any luck with this? I appear to be having a similar problem.

Comment: @bugfixr sorry brother I noticed you message today, I don't remember if I was able to get rid of those but one thing i remember was that i shifted to framework 4.0 from framework 3.5, it helped partially or fully i don't remember but it helped me somehow. sorry for late response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution back in 2010 but I forgot to post it. I actually lost exact track but I remember it was .Net library bug which was reported to microsoft and was acknowledged by them. I don't have its link but I would post it as soon as I able to find it. Anyway Microsoft has fixed this issue in .net 4.0 and that is the exact solution I followed, I know for some of you it might not be possible due to change to server environment is sometimes not in your hands.

Answer (score 6):

You're requesting a new instance per call (InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerCall). If there is no GC happening in the 1000 calls then the service instances will be uncollected. WCF requires you implement IDisposable

From [MSDN : Discover Mighty Instance Management Techniques For Developing WCF Apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/msdn-magazine-issues)

**Per-Call Services**
Per-call services are the Windows Communication Foundation default instantiation mode. When the service type is configured for per-call activation, a service instance, a common language runtime (CLR) object, exists only while a client call is in progress. Every client request gets a new dedicated service instance. Figure 2 illustrates how this single-call activation works.

[image: Figure 2 Per-Call Instantiation]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/cc163590.fig02(en-us).gif))</sub>

1. The client calls the proxy and the
   proxy forwards the call to the
   service.
2. Windows Communication Foundation creates a service
   instance and calls the method on it.
3. **After the method call returns, if the object implements
   IDisposable, then Windows
   Communication Foundation calls
   IDisposable.Dispose on it.**

Comment: I have seen this article before and its true that it call Dispose method automatically if there is any and this is only if you have opened some resource by yourself and need to cleanup in this case you are required to clean them by yourself. But in my case i have no resource to clean. However i have already tried this but same result. Moreover i would like to tell you that GC have cleaned the Heap but Native memory is not cleaned due to those objects were collected UNDisposed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you by any chance enable performance counters? Like below?

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics performanceCounters="All" />
  ..
</system.serviceModel>
```

In paragraph "Increasing Memory Size for Performance Counters", from this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx

there's mention of a "rogue" Private Bytes count when WCF performance counters are enabled. Changing it into ServiceOnly or completely disabling it (Off) may do the trick.