# Performance Counters and WCF Channel leaking

Tags: wcf, performancecounter

What performance counter should I use to detect WCF channel leaking (client use the channel but does not close it at the end)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check

[WCF Service Memory Leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818396/wcf-service-memory-leaks)